# How do I specify an optional entity relationship in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have to entities, `Product` and `HqSettings`.

A `Product` always have an `HqId`.

However, I want to have an optional `HqSettings`, where `HqId` is the PK, and that entity contains some settings specific for the `HqId`.

`HqSettings` does not always exists; as it is supposed to only be used for overriding the default behavior in the applications.

Ie, the models I've created looks like:

```
public class Product 
{
  public PropertyId Id {get;set;}
  public HqId HqId {get;set;}
  public HqSettings? HqSettings {get;set;}

  // other properties
}


public class HqSettings
{
  public HqId HqId {get;set;}

  //other properties
}
```

If I write this then a migration adds a *new* nullable column called `hq_settings_hq_id` but I want it to always use HqId.

I've also tried this (and added an `ICollection<Product>` to `HqSettings`), but it gives the same result with a new nullable column.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<HqSettings>()
    .HasMany(hqSettings => hqSettings.Products)
    .WithOne(product => product.HqSettings)
    .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.HqId)
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Can I achieve this with EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

Manually specify the Foreign Key property to avoid EF Core using a shadow property to define the relationship:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<HqSettings>()
    .HasMany(hqSettings => hqSettings.Products)
    .WithOne(product => product.HqSettings)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.HqId)     // <-- add this line
    .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.HqId)
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/foreign-and-principal-keys

Comment: And make the Foreign Key property nullable.